# How to bind a string to a class?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this code:

```
Join<Tuple2<CustomerScramble, OrdersScramble>> join = joinComponent
                .from(CustomerScrambleManager.IDENTIFIER)
                .innerJoinOn(OrdersScramble.O_CUSTKEY).equal(CustomerScramble.C_CUSTKEY)
                .build(Tuples::of);
```

and I wanted to replace "CustomerScramble" and "OrdersScramble" with a variable. That way:

```
String customerS = "CustomerScramble";
String ordersS = "OrdersScramble";
Join<Tuple2<customerS, ordersS>> join = joinComponent
                .from(CustomerScrambleManager.IDENTIFIER)
                .innerJoinOn(OrdersScramble.O_CUSTKEY).equal(CustomerScramble.C_CUSTKEY)
                .build(Tuples::of);
```

Is this possible ? Because I get the error: "unknown class: x".

Comment: No, you cannot define generic types (what's in between the `<` and `>`) with `String`s. However, you can use unknown generic types and bind them if you need to. Have a look at the tutorial trail [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) to get started.

Comment: just changing the type in the `tuple2` will not suffice anyway. You are also using CusomterScrambleManager, OrdersScramble and CustomerScramble. All those should be coming as parameter too?

Comment: yes @Wisthler, everyone should come as a parameter.

Comment: then go on, with the tutorial from @Mena related to reflections and my tips you should be able to move on. Come back to us once you tried if you are blocked again